# update is not working

Tags: updates

When I try to update or install new software it is not working. In addition, there is some white dashed red circle on the top right. I have asked similar question but none of the answers are working.

```
demisew@DemisewT:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for demisew: 
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list-30Aug2016' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/andykimpe-idm-xenial.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
demisew@DemisewT:~$
```

Comment: Perhaps paste the relevant line into the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Software and update.`

Select tab **"Other Software"**

There you can add or remove repositories.

Or from the terminal -

`sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:<ppa to remove>`

Or, edit the /etc/apt/sources.list to find your ppa there, and remove from there manually

And last option and then update.

> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
>
> sudo apt-get update